# Is it bad to use Bootstrap and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning to become a web developer. I know quite a bit of (OOP) PHP. I know a little Javascript but not much, mostly just do jQuery for simple things. I usually just use Bootstrap for the styling. Should I learn to style myself with CSS (or something like SASS) and get good with vanilla JavaScript? Would it be better for a future in web design?

Comment: This is an opinion based question. Which I think is not for stackoverflow. However (my personal opinion), I suggest you first learn how to use CSS / Javascript without Jquery and bootstrap. This way you will not be dependent on external libraries.

Comment: Bootstrap *itself* uses jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, try to avoid libraries while you learn JavaScript well. But one caveat, jQuery will make your life a lot easier for things like browser compatibility. And it can be very useful for semi-complicated stuff like animations.

The best tips for learning JavaScript are to check out Doug Crockford's videos on YouTube, and if you want to get right in at the nuts and bolts of the language, then pick up a copy of The Definitive Javascript, which Doug Crockford admits is the best book available on the subject.

http://www.amazon.co.uk/JavaScript-Definitive-Guide-David-Flanagan/dp/0596101996

See this vid to get you started:

http://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=Doug%20Crockford&qs=n&form=QBVR&pq=doug%20crockford&sc=2-14&sp=-1&sk=#view=detail&mid=2AC2E38A0E1544A05C782AC2E38A0E1544A05C78

And good luck. You'll love JavaScript if you learn it properly.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is for me a must. Other people think different. But the most are using it! I like e.G. the ultra fast ajax implemetation (most time in just one line).

Another benefit is, that you can find many many plugins. Just google for "top10 jQuery slider" or "top10 alert jQuery plugin" etc...

Bootstrap is for me a "nogo"!. When i see a bootstrap pages (not twitter!), than im thinking: "The company dont want to spend money for a webdesigner".

If you are interested in responsive gridsystems than google for "lightweight gridsystems". There a re about 10 well documented ones.